# Stick a div to a div when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please check fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/howtoplease/f8sXN/4/

I want to make `.float` sticky by jQuery to `.right` when scroll.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="float">
        float
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Stick float to me
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.main{
    margin-bottom:30px;

}
.float{
    background:  #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 40px;
}
.right{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #AAAAAA;
    height: 245px;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f8sXN/7/ is this what you mean with "sticky"?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/f8sXN/8/ is this what you want ?

Comment: @AndreasBjørn no, it is floating whole div, I just want make `.float` when scroll

Comment: In that case I think @UDB is spot on.

Comment: no it is also not working... kindly see here how voting are float when scroll, I want the same thing: http://www.quora.com/Bootstrap-front-end-framework/Why-did-Twitter-use-LESS-instead-of-Sass-for-Bootstrap

Comment: Ah, in that case, you'll have to write some jQuery code: 1) Check if browser has scrolled to the point where the div should detach 2) Apply some CSS class where div is now fixed and detached 3) If browser scrolls back up past the point, remove the class so it returns to its static position. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

altered `Mark S`'s answer to keep the `.float` on left side like the page whose link is provided in comment

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

$('.main').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        offset = $this.offset(),
        h = $this.height();

    if (st >= offset.top && st < offset.top + h - 40) {
        $this.find('.float').css({
            'margin-top': st - offset.top + 'px'
        });
    } else if (st >= offset.top + h + 30/*.main margin-bottom*/) {
        $this.find('.float').css({
            'margin-top': 'auto'
        });
    }


})
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f8sXN/10/)

Comment: Wow this solution is also amazing, I like it cuz `float` does not suddenly disappear like @Mark s

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

$('.main').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), 
        offset = $this.offset(),
        h = $this.height(),
        $float = $this.find('.float'),
        floatH = $float.height();

    if(st >= offset.top && st < offset.top + h - floatH){
        $float.css({'position':'fixed'});
    }else{
        $float.css({'position':'absolute'});
    }
})
});
```

CSS:

```
.main{
    margin-bottom:30px;
    /* set main to realtive so float won't move out bounds */
    position:relative;
}

.float{
    background:  #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    /* set top to 0 and position to absolute*/
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
}

.right{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #AAAAAA;
    height: 245px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    /* the float width:40 plus its margin-right:20 that I removed*/
    margin-left:60px; 
}
```

I've updated the answer to solve the issue on `'.right'` — maintaining the same width and position.

Similar to @UDB solution, but on that method (changing `'margin-top'`) I noticed the `'.float'` sometimes shaking especially on long scroll and scrolling fast this happens:
[image]

On my new solution we're only changing the `position` property so no issue so far.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/f8sXN/12/).

Thanks also to @Zeaklous and @UDB ideas.

Comment: Check your lower bounds, subtract the height of the float